# Bootstrap navbar toggle button does not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the page is reduced to tablet/mobile size, the toggle button is displayed but does not work. Here is the html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

....
....


<script type="text/javascript" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The necessary javascript is linked.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue; it is very slight.  The href attribute should be replaced with a src attribute on script tags.  Sublime Text's tab press for script defaults an href.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  left: -300px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
body{
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://freelancezonebd.com/sb-web/3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </nav>

....
....


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call bootstrap.css as well . Here i just called it from my local file

```
<link href="http://freelancezonebd.com/sb-web/3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

You can call it from CDN. And also to call js files use "src" instead of "href" . Thank you.

```css
.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  left: -300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://freelancezonebd.com/sb-web/3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </nav>

....
....


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```